# Label background colour changed when UITableViewCell selected

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, uilabel

I have added a custom label in UITableViewCell. Its background color is red and the font is white. When I select any cell then selected cell's label background color changed into grey.

For reference, I am adding code

```
let lblUnreadCount = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
let size:CGFloat = 20.0
lblUnreadCount.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 28.0, height: 20.0)
lblUnreadCount.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2
lblUnreadCount.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
lblUnreadCount.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
lblUnreadCount.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

For reference, I am also adding a screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: set selection to none

Answer (score 1):

It's not the label's background that's changing but the cell itself. In your `cellForRow` method, after you've `dequeued` the cell, use this

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Comment: But this is not showing me highlighted selected cell. I want that's too.

Comment: Do you want it to be changed to red when selected?

Comment: change view background color when selected.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like setting cell style to .none is not what OP wanted as it actually clears the cell's highlighted color when selected.

I found it a bit tricky to achieve like this (clear the TextLabel bg color and set the bg color to its layer):

```
// Note that cell background color must be cleared **before** setting layer color
lblUnreadCount.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
lblUnreadCount.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

This way you will be able to keep the bg color of the text label (within the cell) unchanged when the cell is selected and highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

1.set selection style none

`UITableViewCell
|
|----- UIView
       |
       |-----UIImageView-> eg:Message icon
       |-----Title Label-> eg:Message
       |-----Count Label-> red background`

2.when cell is selected you have to change the UIView background color(gray).

Answer (score 0):

set background color of your label inside UITableViewCell.In above code you set the label's layer background color.

lblUnreadCount.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor